# How to include the moment.js library in a Laravel project?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, momentjs

I am creating a project in Laravel.
In order to create charts in chart.js, I need to include the moment.js library in the project.
But I am getting errors connecting the moment.js library.

Run the directive on the command line `npm install moment --save`
Next, I include the library itself in parent blade template:

- if I connect `<script src="node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>`, I get an error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

- if I include `<script src="{{ asset(node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js) }}"></script>`, I get an error

> Undefined constant "node_modules"

Comment: Agree.
1)  I tried "<script src="{{ url(node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js) }}"></script>", but get an error "Undefined constant "node_modules""   2)  I connect in the balde template

Comment: If node_modules folder in public folder, then <script src="{{ asset('node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js') }}"></script>

Comment: found a post where the author connects the library not in the blade template but in the app.js file
Tried and same error

Comment: Can you show app.js code? how did you imported moment.js over there?

Comment: at the beginning, I connected the library as described in the text of the question  , but then i connect library : in  app.js  did  "import '../../node_modules/moment'' end delete  <script src="{{ asset(node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js) }}"></script> in my blade

Answer (score 0):

You can't access root folders like node_modules because the domain name (localhost) is pointing to /public directory that's how laravel serve your files, so if you want to include that script you can either download it and put it somewhere under /public directory or just use [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) for importing js script it's very helpful specially with laravel (check [Vite with Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles)).